# Get String after a HTML tag using a parser

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to developing a **scraper** application.

Below is html structure,we need to get City/State name.
its "**Daviston, AL**" in below example. can anyone please help me here.

```
<div class="post-entry">
    <h2 class="entry-title">
        <a title="Horseshoe Bend National Military Park" href="http://www.parks.us/id-2755/">Horseshoe Bend National Military Park</a>
    </h2>
    <strong>City/State: </strong> Daviston, AL
    <p><span><em>Activities include:</em> Auto Touring, Biking, Boating, Fishing, Hiking, Picnicking, Water Sports, Wildlife Viewing</span></p>
</div>
```

with this code , i am just getting "**City/State**"

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=post-entry]') as details){
    $Details->find('strong',0)->plaintext
}
```

Comment: The value you're looking for isn't wrapped in the `<strong>` tag.
It's actually not being wrapped by any tag so it's a more complicated case.
You need to fetch the all `class="post-entry"` content and using php (regex) get the mentioned value.

Comment: Do not include tags in question name, thank you on behalf of the community.

Comment: Actually, if you just remove all the child nodes, what's left is the text you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- Traverse children of div[class=post-entry].
- Skip h2
- Skip strong
- Get text node (Daviston, AL)